# How to pass dictionary from Django view to JavaScript and access dictionary value with keys

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, dictionary

I want to pass a dictionary to JavaScript/jQuery from Django view. In JavaScript i want to access my send dictionary values with the keys. Here I provided my view and JS code.

View:

```
def student(request):
    data={
        {
        'name': "Joe",
        'age' :15,
        },
        {
            'name': "Jay",
            'age' :16,
        },
        {
            'name': "Jeff",
            'age' :14,
        },
    }
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("click","#button",function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
               $.ajax({
                    method:"POST",
                    url: "{% url 'student'  %}",
                    data: {
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}',
                    },
                    success: function(response){
                        console.log(response[0].name);
                        console.log(response[0].age);
               },
                    error: function(){
                        console.log("error occur");
                        
                    },

               });
               
           });
```

With this code i didn't accomplish what i wanted to.

Edit: In console i have checked response and i got TypeError, Its says unhashable type: 'dict' .

Comment: Hi @Travis, please share inside your question the error that you are getting. This will help you out debug your issue and other members understand/assume the root of the problem

Answer (score 0):

instead of returning a HTTP response try returning Jsonresponse. return statement will be like this:
"return JsonRespnse({data})"